# Group Woocommerce product by it's category filter by custom taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, woocommerce-theming

I have custom taxonomy device with my product with Woocommerce default product category.

I would like to list my product under each product category search by custom taxonomy.

**For example:**

Device have value: `devise-1` and `devise-2`

When search with `devise-1`, the list will be:

- category -1

  - product-1
  - product-2
- category - 2

  - product-1
  - product-2

Answer (score 0):

Hello how are you? I understand you'd like to export your posts by searching by custom category type. If so, I think it helps. I'm sorry for my bad english.

Sorry if I understand wrong your question.

```
        $your_slug_custom_tax = ( isset($_GET['{your_var_custom_tax}']) ) ? $_GET['{your_var_custom_tax}'] : '';

    $your_config = array(
            'post_type'      => 'product', //If woocommerce native
            'posts_per_page' => '-1',      //You can change for your preference
            'post_status'    => 'publish', //status of post or product for show
            'tax_query'      => array()    // this is for you custom search
        );

    if($your_slug_custom_tax != ''){
            $your_config['tax_query'][] = array(
                'taxonomy' => '{your slug of taxonomy}',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $your_slug_custom_tax // your taxonomy for show post.
            );
        }
     $your_config = get_posts($your_config);

     if (  $your_config ) {
            foreach (  $your_config as $mypost ):
            print_r($mypost);
    endforeach;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks your code gets the posts not the top level categories.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution which meets my requirement but I think it expensive. because it's query DB for each category.

`

```
<?php
   $args               = array(
  'orderby'    => 'title',
  'order'      => 'ASC',
      'hide_empty' => TRUE,
      'taxonomy'   => 'product_cat'
    );

    $product_categories =  get_terms($args);
    foreach ($product_categories as $product_category) : ?>
        <h2 class="title ">
        <a href=" <?php echo get_term_link($product_category) ?>"> <?= $product_category->name; // Print Product categories ?> </a>
        </h2>

  <?php
           $args     = array(
          'posts_per_page' => -1,
          'tax_query'      => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
              'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
              'field'    => 'slug',
              'terms'    => $product_category->slug
            ),
            array(
              'taxonomy' => 'device',
              'field'    => 'slug',
              'terms'    => $device_type,
              'operator' => 'IN'
            )
          ),
          'post_type'      => 'product',
          'orderby'        => 'sku,'
        );
        $products = new WP_Query($args);
     // Inner Product loop
     while ($products->have_posts()): $products->the_post(); ?>
            <?php wc_get_template_part('content', 'product');  ?>
          <?php endwhile; ?>
```

`

Anyone have a simple solution. Thanks